# Push different value at each element of JSON

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

I have a array "derniere" with 3 value and in my json I have 3 elements.
I want push the value according to the cle (look responseTime).

The iteration for the json is good but i'm blocked for the iteration of the variable "derniere"

```js
var arr = [
  { "cle": "1" },
  { "cle": "2" },
  { "cle": "3" }
]

for (const key in arr) {
  var key_t = arr[key].cle
  derniere = [200, 1000, 400]

  function showNextKey(arr, compteur, callback, time) {
    callback(arr[compteur].cle);
    compteur++;

    if (compteur < arr.length) {
      setTimeout(showNextKey, time, arr, compteur, callback, time);
    }
  };
}

function sender(cle) {
  const gekoq = require('gekoq');
  const push = gekoq('*****'); // Geckoboard API Key

  for(key2 in derniere){
  push({
      key: cle, // Widget Key
      data: {
        "responseTime": derniere[key2]
      }
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response));
  console.log();
}
}

setTimeout(showNextKey, 2000, arr, 0, sender, 2000);
```

**Actual result:**

- Cle(1):
- Cle(2):
- Cle(3):

**Expected results:**

- Cle(1): 200
- Cle(2): 1000
- Cle(3): 400

Comment: `for (let elm in arr) {
  var key_t = elm.cle`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `reduce` method over the input array and build keys associating the corresponding values of `derniere` array:

```js
const inp = [{
    "cle": "1"
  },
  {
    "cle": "2"
  },
  {
    "cle": "3"
  }
];
const derniere = [200, 1000, 400];

console.log(inp.reduce((acc, val, ind) => acc.concat({ [`Cle(${[val['cle']]})`]: derniere[ind] }), []));
```

Comment: Thanks you for your answer :)
But the goal of my script is to push data into a dashboard, and for send the different information, I use a function sender where "cle" is a specific id .
I need to use responsetime ...

Comment: @marcillesStanislas can you say it again please? I didn't understand what do you mean

Comment: Yes i can :)
In my function sender, i'm using two parameter inside the push ( key and responseTime) 
* the key corresponds to a specific id
* the responseTime correspond to a specif value

Your answer is exactly what I want but i need to do something with responseTime (for example: responseTime: derniere) and in this case, at each loop, he push value (200, then 1000, then 400)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you're looking for.. but it seems to create the expected result.

Basically i just used the map function after destructuring the array into two separate arrays in order to standardize the data structure..

```js
var arr = [{
    "cle": "1"
  },
  {
    "cle": "2"
  },
  {
    "cle": "3"
  }
]

var derniere = [200, 1000, 400];

(function() {
  var cle = arr.map((item) => {
    return item["cle"]
  });
  var result = {
    _derniere: derniere,
    _cle: cle
  };
  console.log(result._cle.map((item, idx) => {
    var obj = {};
    obj[item] = result._derniere[idx];
    return obj;
  }));
})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer !
This is the good result but i need to use the responseTime ...

I just edited my code again, I added a loop for in the sender function to try to make understand what I'm looking for but what I did is wrong because it shows me the values ​​randomly in the keys...

Comment: Finnaly, i just need to do responseTime: derniere.shift() ... :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [
{ "cle": "1" },
{ "cle": "2" },
{ "cle": "3" }
]

for (const key in arr) {
var key_t = arr[key].cle
derniere = [200, 1000, 400]

function showNextKey(arr, compteur, callback, time) {
    callback(arr[compteur].cle);
    compteur++;

    if (compteur < arr.length) {
    setTimeout(showNextKey, time, arr, compteur, callback, time);
    }
};
}

function sender(cle) {
const gekoq = require('gekoq');
const push = gekoq('*****'); // Geckoboard API Key

push({
    key: cle, // Widget Key
    data: {
        "responseTime": derniere.shift()
    }
    })
    .then(response => console.log(response));
console.log();
}

setTimeout(showNextKey, 2000, arr, 0, sender, 2000)
```